# Zend Auth - Using two tables

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

I'm currently developing a website in Zend Framework wich uses Zend_Auth. The current design of the database is the following:

- users - id / email
- users_props - id - user_id - prop_name - prop_value

However, the current Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable uses only one table, as where I have to tables and need to join them.

How on earth can I do this? As far as i'm concerned, there are three options:

1. I somehow create a (mysql) view
2. I change the design so the users table contains both username/password
3. I rewrite the Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable to a Custom_Auth_Adapter_DbTabe

Can anyone point me out what the best practise is?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper thing to do is to create a custom `Zend_Auth_Adapter` that authentication to your particular DB schema.

Its actually pretty easy, there is only a single method in the interface to implemnt. Its also possible you could jsut extend `Zend_Auth_Db_Adapter` and override methods as necessary. Probably only what builds executes and returns the query result. But honestly i would just implment the interfae from scratch were it me. A lot easier that way IMO :-)

Comment: Your comment made me realise I was searching wrong. It's pretty easy actually. For others looking for Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable wanting to use two columns; write your own Custon_Auth_Adapter. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328047/creating-own-zend-auth-adapter :)