# Zend Login using multiple tables

Tags: zend-framework

How can I authenticate a user whose username is in one table and password is in another table `Zend_Auth`?

I have `user_id` common in both tables. I am developing a simple login module using 2 tables.

Comment: You need to write your own authentication apdater.

Comment: show us the both the table. and we can guide you.

Comment: `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` is not supporting this kind of authentication. I believe you have to extend this class give it additional param like 'credential_table_name' and overload the function to create select query to use join statment.

Comment: One simple solution is to create a database view to federate your data.  Alternately what Florent has suggested.  [Here](http://robertbasic.com/blog/login-example-with-zend_auth/) is a good resource.

Comment: And asked here before too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116314/zend-auth-using-two-tables